# Getting java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, servlets

I am creating a website using JDBC,I get the following error while running TOMCAT and what should I do to solve this,I have created 6 columns in MYSQL workbench as uname,pass,name,city,email,phone   but still getting this error.

this is my register.java servlet file ,I run this and copy paste the class i get to the WEB-INF/classes folder

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException{
        response.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/form","root","sudhakar");

            String uname = request.getParameter("uname");
            String psw = request.getParameter("psw");
            String nam = request.getParameter("nam");
            String cit = request.getParameter("cit");
            String ema = request.getParameter("ema");
            String num = request.getParameter("num");
                    PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("insert into login values(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                    pst.setString(1,uname);
                    pst.setString(2,psw);
                    pst.setString(3,nam);
                    pst.setString(4,cit);
                    pst.setString(5,ema);
                    pst.setString(6,num);
                    pst.executeUpdate();
                    out.print("Successs");

        }catch(Exception e){
            out.print(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: login is another table,and i completed it its working fine but this register doesnt seem to work

Comment: sorry my bad,I was doing trial and error,I changed to 6 question marks and still the same outcome    PS:editing the question to 6 parameters itself now

Comment: Still getting the same error bro

Comment: please show your table structure i.e. the create statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your SQL statement to be:

```
insert into login(uname,pass,name,city,email,phone) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

It's generally advisable to always explicitly name your columns, so that your statement carries on working if new (nullable/sensibly defaulted) columns are added, or stops working when columns are renamed or deleted, and it also makes your code more self-documenting